# iphone sdk 4.3 gdb notice

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gdb

New to coding here. I have worked on a simple code on sdk 4.3, when compiled i get a gdb error "GDB: Stopped at breakpoint 3 (hit count: 1)- 'Line:5'
Can someone please break this down for me and explain what that exactly means?

Answer (score 1):

There is breakpoint set in your code and application stops on it if you try to Debug. Press "Run" -> "Run - Breakpoints Off" or remove breakpoint from project to run application without stopping. You can locate breakpoints on the left side of source code - they look like blue arrows. Delete breakpoint by dragging it to left/right or locate Breakpoints in Groups & Files view of Xcode and delete it there (look at the bottom for Breakpoints).